# Iteration over list slices

Tags: python, loops, iteration, slice

I want an algorithm to iterate over list slices. Slices size is set outside the function and can differ.

In my mind it is something like:

```
for list_of_x_items in fatherList:
    foo(list_of_x_items)
```

Is there a way to properly define `list_of_x_items` or some other way of doing this using python 2.5?

---

**edit1: Clarification** Both "partitioning" and "sliding window" terms sound applicable to my task, but I am no expert. So I will explain  the problem a bit deeper and add to the question:

The fatherList is a multilevel numpy.array I am getting from a file. Function has to find averages of series (user provides the length of series) For averaging I am using the `mean()` function. Now for question expansion:

**edit2:** How to modify the function you have provided to store the extra items and use them when the next fatherList is fed to the function?

for example if the list is lenght 10 and size of a chunk is 3, then the 10th member of the list is stored and appended to the beginning of the next list.

---

#### Related:

- [What is the most “pythonic” way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)

Comment: You seem to be describing an operation that works on subsets of the original list.  "slices" can refer to the individual contiguous ranges, but the operation you're looking for is often called "partitioning". You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198512/split-a-list-into-parts-based-on-a-set-of-indexes-in-python

Comment: I was actually thinking of what is sometimes refered to as a "sliding window" of width n over a sequence, but looking at Nadia's answer there is this other interpretation of the question, which is probably closer to "partitioning". Maybe the OP will clarify this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Answer to the last part of the question:

> question update: How to modify the
>   function you have provided to store
>   the extra items and use them when the
>   next fatherList is fed to the
>   function?

If you need to store state then you can use an object for that.

```
class Chunker(object):
    """Split `iterable` on evenly sized chunks.

    Leftovers are remembered and yielded at the next call.
    """
    def __init__(self, chunksize):
        assert chunksize > 0
        self.chunksize = chunksize        
        self.chunk = []

    def __call__(self, iterable):
        """Yield items from `iterable` `self.chunksize` at the time."""
        assert len(self.chunk) < self.chunksize
        for item in iterable:
            self.chunk.append(item)
            if len(self.chunk) == self.chunksize:
                # yield collected full chunk
                yield self.chunk
                self.chunk = []
```

Example:

```
chunker = Chunker(3)
for s in "abcd", "efgh":
    for chunk in chunker(s):
        print ''.join(chunk)

if chunker.chunk: # is there anything left?
    print ''.join(chunker.chunk)
```

Output:

```
abc
def
gh
```

Comment: There needs to be another yield self.chunk after the for loop to account for chunks that aren't the full chunksize. Otherwise this won't work on arbitrary list sizes.

Comment: @aryeh: `__call__` may be called more than once, therefore you can't just yield leftovers after the for loop. That's the point of the class. It answers *"to store the extra items and use them when the next fatherList is fed to the function"* part of the question as explicitly stated at the top of the answer.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't read the question/example carefully enough.  I thought it was just for grouping.  I personally dislike the extra check at the end and would vote to add an option to __call__ whether to save extra items or flush them at the end, so you wouldn't need to possibly duplicate the body of the for loop in a following if statement.

Answer (score 74):

If you want to divide a list into slices you can use this trick:

```
list_of_slices = zip(*(iter(the_list),) * slice_size)
```

For example

```
>>> zip(*(iter(range(10)),) * 3)
[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)]
```

If the number of items is not dividable by the slice size and you want to pad the list with None you can do this:

```
>>> map(None, *(iter(range(10)),) * 3)
[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, None, None)]
```

It is a dirty little trick

---

OK, I'll explain how it works. It'll be tricky to explain but I'll try my best.

First a little background:

In Python you can multiply a list by a number like this:

```
[1, 2, 3] * 3 -> [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
([1, 2, 3],) * 3 -> ([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
```

And an [iterator](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=iter#iter) object can be consumed once like this:

```
>>> l=iter([1, 2, 3])
>>> l.next()
1
>>> l.next()
2
>>> l.next()
3
```

The [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. For example:

```
zip([1, 2, 3], [20, 30, 40]) -> [(1, 20), (2, 30), (3, 40)]
zip(*[(1, 20), (2, 30), (3, 40)]) -> [[1, 2, 3], [20, 30, 40]]
```

The * in front of zip used to unpack arguments. You can find more details [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).
So

```
zip(*[(1, 20), (2, 30), (3, 40)])
```

is actually equivalent to

```
zip((1, 20), (2, 30), (3, 40))
```

but works with a variable number of arguments

Now back to the trick:

```
list_of_slices = zip(*(iter(the_list),) * slice_size)
```

`iter(the_list)` -> convert the list into an iterator

`(iter(the_list),) * N` -> will generate an N reference to the_list iterator.

`zip(*(iter(the_list),) * N)` -> will feed those list of iterators into zip. Which in turn will group them into N sized tuples. But since all N items are in fact references to the same iterator `iter(the_list)` the result will be repeated calls to `next()` on the original iterator

I hope that explains it. I advice you to go with an easier to understand solution. I was only tempted to mention this trick because I like it.

Comment: One interesting thing is also that you're silently making use of the ``*`` unpacking operator's low precedence, which allows funny constructs like `` f(*L*N)``, and which I find nowhere documented.

Comment: @ThomasH: `f(*args)` is an extended call syntax in Python. You can put anything that evaluates to an iterable on the right side of asterisk (`*`) e.g., [`f(*[1]+g())`](http://ideone.com/2yP70)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, thanks. What struck me was just the operator precedence for this. Your example resolves to `f(*([1]+g()))`.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to be able to consume any iterable you can use these functions:

```
from itertools import chain, islice

def ichunked(seq, chunksize):
    """Yields items from an iterator in iterable chunks."""
    it = iter(seq)
    while True:
        yield chain([it.next()], islice(it, chunksize-1))

def chunked(seq, chunksize):
    """Yields items from an iterator in list chunks."""
    for chunk in ichunked(seq, chunksize):
        yield list(chunk)
```

Comment: Very beautiful. And you can actually make it smarter by adding a parameter to choose the type of each chunk: https://gist.github.com/1275417.

Comment: In Python 3 it is `next(it)` instead of `it.next()`. For those wondering: `islice` doesn't raise a StopIteration, that's why we call `next`.

Comment: @Tim-Erwin I tried it in python 3.6 by changing to `next(it)` however I get the warning `DeprecationWarning: generator 'ichunked' raised StopIteration`. I don't understand where this is being raised, as it's not explicit.

Comment: @meowsqueak It is raised in `next()`. That's expected in Python 3.5 and below, deprecated in 3.6, broken in 3.7. I added a version compatible with 3.7+ in the answer.

Answer (score 12):

Use a generator:

```
big_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
slice_length = 3
def sliceIterator(lst, sliceLen):
    for i in range(len(lst) - sliceLen + 1):
        yield lst[i:i + sliceLen]

for slice in sliceIterator(big_list, slice_length):
    foo(slice)
```

`sliceIterator` implements a "sliding window" of width `sliceLen` over the squence `lst`, i.e. it produces overlapping slices: [1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], ... Not sure if that is the OP's intention, though.

Answer (score 9):

Do you mean something like:

```
def callonslices(size, fatherList, foo):
  for i in xrange(0, len(fatherList), size):
    foo(fatherList[i:i+size])
```

If this is roughly the functionality you want you might, if you desire, dress it up a bit in a generator:

```
def sliceup(size, fatherList):
  for i in xrange(0, len(fatherList), size):
    yield fatherList[i:i+size]
```

and then:

```
def callonslices(size, fatherList, foo):
  for sli in sliceup(size, fatherList):
    foo(sli)
```

Comment: I think you'll get lists of irregular size with that. No telling exactly what the OP wanted, but this might be closer: for i in xrange(0, len(fatherList)-size, 1):

Comment: Correction: for i in xrange(len(fatherList) - size + 1):

Comment: "irregular size"? they're all of len `size` except possibly for the last one -- and nonoverlapping. Consider what happens with your code when the len is 6 and the size is 7, say... 5 slices of decreasing length...

Comment: Better;-) but with len 6 and size 8 you still have the same problem.

Comment: I was searing for something nice that would work out of the box as it looks as TOTALY general problem. My note: Nice&simple implementation but not to use with iterators... :( No len(list(fatherList)) is not it.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure, but it seems you want to do what is called a moving average. numpy provides facilities for this (the convolve function).

```
>>> x = numpy.array(range(20))
>>> x
    array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19])    
>>> n = 2 # moving average window
>>> numpy.convolve(numpy.ones(n)/n, x)[n-1:-n+1]
array([  0.5,   1.5,   2.5,   3.5,   4.5,   5.5,   6.5,   7.5,   8.5,
         9.5,  10.5,  11.5,  12.5,  13.5,  14.5,  15.5,  16.5,  17.5,  18.5])
```

The nice thing is that it accomodates different weighting schemes nicely (just change `numpy.ones(n) / n` to something else).

You can find a complete material here:
http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/SignalSmooth

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on the answer of @Ants Aasma: In Python 3.7 the handling of the `StopIteration` exception [changed](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) (according to [PEP-479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/)). A compatible version would be:

```
from itertools import chain, islice

def ichunked(seq, chunksize):
    it = iter(seq)
    while True:
        try:
            yield chain([next(it)], islice(it, chunksize - 1))
        except StopIteration:
            return
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question could use some more detail, but how about:

```
def iterate_over_slices(the_list, slice_size):
    for start in range(0, len(the_list)-slice_size):
        slice = the_list[start:start+slice_size]
        foo(slice)
```

Answer (score 2):

For a near-one liner (after `itertools` import) in the vein of Nadia's answer dealing with non-chunk divisible sizes without padding:

```
>>> import itertools as itt
>>> chunksize = 5
>>> myseq = range(18)
>>> cnt = itt.count()
>>> print [ tuple(grp) for k,grp in itt.groupby(myseq, key=lambda x: cnt.next()//chunksize%2)]
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12, 13, 14), (15, 16, 17)]
```

If you want, you can get rid of the `itertools.count()` requirement using `enumerate()`, with a rather uglier:

```
[ [e[1] for e in grp] for k,grp in itt.groupby(enumerate(myseq), key=lambda x: x[0]//chunksize%2) ]
```

(In this example the `enumerate()` would be superfluous, but not all sequences are neat ranges like this, obviously)

Nowhere near as neat as some other answers, but useful in a pinch, especially if already importing `itertools`.

Answer (score 0):

A function that slices a list or an iterator into chunks of a given size. Also handles the case correctly if the last chunk is smaller:

```
def slice_iterator(data, slice_len):
    it = iter(data)
    while True:
        items = []
        for index in range(slice_len):
            try:
                item = next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                if items == []:
                    return # we are done
                else:
                    break # exits the "for" loop
            items.append(item)
        yield items
```

Usage example:

```
for slice in slice_iterator([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],3):
    print(slice)
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
[10]
```

Comment: Does what some of the other solutions do in more lines, maybe a little slower, depending on the use case. This could be improved using islice.