# Slicing a list into n nearly-equal-length partitions

Tags: python, list, slice

I'm looking for a fast, clean, pythonic way to divide a list into exactly n nearly-equal partitions.

```
partition([1,2,3,4,5],5)->[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]
partition([1,2,3,4,5],2)->[[1,2],[3,4,5]] (or [[1,2,3],[4,5]])
partition([1,2,3,4,5],3)->[[1,2],[3,4],[5]] (there are other ways to slice this one too)
```

There are several answers in here [Iteration over list slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335392/iteration-over-list-slices) that run very close to what I want, except they are focused on the *size* of the list, and I care about the *number* of the lists (some of them also pad with None).  These are trivially converted, obviously, but I'm looking for a best practice.

Similarly, people have pointed out great solutions here [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) for a very similar problem, but I'm more interested in the number of partitions than the specific size, as long as it's within 1.  Again, this is trivially convertible, but I'm looking for a best practice.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
def partition(lst, n):
    division = len(lst) / float(n)
    return [ lst[int(round(division * i)): int(round(division * (i + 1)))] for i in xrange(n) ]

>>> partition([1,2,3,4,5],5)
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
>>> partition([1,2,3,4,5],2)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
>>> partition([1,2,3,4,5],3)
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
>>> partition(range(105), 10)
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31], [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41], [42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52], [53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62], [63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73], [74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83], [84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94], [95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104]]
```

Python 3 version:

```
def partition(lst, n):
    division = len(lst) / n
    return [lst[round(division * i):round(division * (i + 1))] for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: That doesn't work for non-trivial examples.  For `partition(range(105), 10)`, the last sublist will have only 6 elements.

Comment: How would you split that list?

Comment: @JG: 5 sublists of 10 items and 5 sublists of 11 items.

Comment: @Daniel: Fair enough, although that isn't very clear in the original question. It is "fixed" now.

Comment: @JG: I believe the “exactly n nearly equal” was meant to be “exactly n of nearly equal length”; the “as long as it's within 1” also is a strong hint, even if vague and unclear.

Answer (score 33):

Just a different take, that only works if `[[1,3,5],[2,4]]` is an acceptable partition, in your example.

```
def partition ( lst, n ):
    return [ lst[i::n] for i in xrange(n) ]
```

This satisfies the example mentioned in @Daniel Stutzbach's example:

```
partition(range(105),10)
# [[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
# [1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91, 101],
# [2, 12, 22, 32, 42, 52, 62, 72, 82, 92, 102],
# [3, 13, 23, 33, 43, 53, 63, 73, 83, 93, 103],
# [4, 14, 24, 34, 44, 54, 64, 74, 84, 94, 104],
# [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95],
# [6, 16, 26, 36, 46, 56, 66, 76, 86, 96],
# [7, 17, 27, 37, 47, 57, 67, 77, 87, 97],
# [8, 18, 28, 38, 48, 58, 68, 78, 88, 98],
# [9, 19, 29, 39, 49, 59, 69, 79, 89, 99]]
```

Comment: This is a wonderfully pythonic solution

Comment: I feel like there must be some clever way to get the original, desired input, but `zip( *partition(range(105),10) )` doesn't work because zip truncates... Still, very nice.

Comment: Oh my gosh, this is wonderful.

Comment: if you used itertools.izip longest, it should work

Comment: Very neat indeed (if you don't require contiguous partitions).

Comment: [Yet another solution (that keeps partitions **contigusous**)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65507032/2325279)

Answer (score 28):

Here's a version that's similar to Daniel's:  it divides as evenly as possible, but puts all the larger partitions at the start:

```
def partition(lst, n):
    q, r = divmod(len(lst), n)
    indices = [q*i + min(i, r) for i in xrange(n+1)]
    return [lst[indices[i]:indices[i+1]] for i in xrange(n)]
```

It also avoids the use of float arithmetic, since that always makes me uncomfortable.  :)

Edit:  an example, just to show the contrast with Daniel Stutzbach's solution

```
>>> print [len(x) for x in partition(range(105), 10)]
[11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

Answer (score 4):

Below is one way.

```
def partition(lst, n):
    increment = len(lst) / float(n)
    last = 0
    i = 1
    results = []
    while last < len(lst):
        idx = int(round(increment * i))
        results.append(lst[last:idx])
        last = idx
        i += 1
    return results
```

If len(lst) cannot be evenly divided by n, this version will distribute the extra items at roughly equal intervals.  For example:

```
>>> print [len(x) for x in partition(range(105), 10)]
[11, 10, 11, 10, 11, 10, 11, 10, 11, 10]
```

The code could be simpler if you don't mind all of the 11s being at the beginning or the end.

Comment: The use of floating-point could result in machine-dependent results: when increment*i is (mathematically) exactly halfway between two integers, the rounding could go either way depending on what numerical errors have been introduced.

How about using something like `idx = len(lst)*i//n` instead?  Or perhaps `idx = (len(lst)*i + n//2)//n` to get results similar to the current code.

Comment: FYI this is the well-known [Bresenham algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

This answer provides a function `split(list_, n, max_ratio)`, for people
who want to split their list into `n` pieces with at most `max_ratio`
ratio in piece length. It allows for more variation than the
questioner's 'at most 1 difference in piece length'.

It works by sampling *n* piece lengths within the desired ratio range
*[1 , max_ratio)*, placing them after each other to form a 'broken
stick' with the right distances between the 'break points' but the wrong
total length. Scaling the broken stick to the desired length gives us
the approximate positions of the break points we want. To get integer
break points requires subsequent rounding.

Unfortunately, the roundings can conspire to make pieces just too short,
and let you exceed the max_ratio. See the bottom of this answer for an
example.

```
import random

def splitting_points(length, n, max_ratio):
    """n+1 slice points [0, ..., length] for n random-sized slices.

    max_ratio is the largest allowable ratio between the largest and the
    smallest part.
    """
    ratios = [random.uniform(1, max_ratio) for _ in range(n)]
    normalized_ratios = [r / sum(ratios) for r in ratios]
    cumulative_ratios = [
        sum(normalized_ratios[0:i])
        for i in range(n+1)
    ]
    scaled_distances = [
        int(round(r * length))
        for r in cumulative_ratios
    ]

    return scaled_distances


def split(list_, n, max_ratio):
    """Slice a list into n randomly-sized parts.

    max_ratio is the largest allowable ratio between the largest and the
    smallest part.
    """

    points = splitting_points(len(list_), n, ratio)

    return [
        list_[ points[i] : points[i+1] ]
        for i in range(n)
    ]
```

You can try it out like so:

```
for _ in range(10):
    parts = split('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 4, 2)
    print([(len(part), part) for part in parts])
```

Example of a bad result:

```
parts = split('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 10, 2)

# lengths range from 1 to 4, not 2 to 4
[(3, 'abc'),  (3, 'def'), (1, 'g'),
 (4, 'hijk'), (3, 'lmn'), (2, 'op'),
 (2, 'qr'),  (3, 'stu'),  (2, 'vw'),
 (3, 'xyz')]
```