# How to randomly partition a list into n nearly equal parts?

Tags: python, random, slice

I have read the answers to the [Slicing a list into n nearly-equal-length partitions [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659900/slicing-a-list-into-n-nearly-equal-length-partitions) question.

This is the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659900/python-slicing-a-list-into-n-nearly-equal-length-partitions/2660034#2660034):

```
def partition(lst, n): 
    division = len(lst) / float(n) 
    return [ lst[int(round(division * i)): int(round(division * (i + 1)))] for i in xrange(n) ]
```

I am wondering, how does one modify these solutions in order to randomly assign items to a partition as opposed to incremental assignment.

Comment: partition is also method of strings so maybe you should reconsider naming. Also I would use the floatless second answer by Mark Dickinson.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Call [`random.shuffle()`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle) on the list before partitioning it.

Answer (score 29):

Complete 2018 solution (python 3.6):

```
import random 
def partition (list_in, n):
    random.shuffle(list_in)
    return [list_in[i::n] for i in range(n)]
```

**Beware!** this may mutate your original list

Comment: "may mutate" => "will mutate", but solving that is as easy as copying the original list

Answer (score 3):

shuffle input list.

Comment: That absolutely makes sense. I really should have figured this out. Alas, the 10,000 hour rule is probably true :-(

Answer (score 2):

First you randomize the list and then you split it in n nearly equal parts.

Answer (score 1):

Shuffling the list doesn't preserve order. You could do something like this instead (pretty easy to adapt to more than two parts). Completely untested.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar
import random

T = TypeVar("T")

def partition_list(s: list[T]) -> tuple[list[T], list[T]]:
    """
    Randomly partition a list into two lists, preserving order. The number to
    take is drawn from a uniform distribution.
    """
    len_a = random.randint(0, len(s))
    len_b = len(s) - len_a
    put_in_a = [True] * len_a + [False] * len_b
    random.shuffle(put_in_a)
    a: list[T] = []
    b: list[T] = []

    for val, in_a in zip(s, put_in_a):
        if in_a:
            a.append(val)
        else:
            b.append(val)

    return a, b
```

Answer (score 0):

The random partition that also preserves the order:

```py
def partition_preserve_order(list_in, n):
    indices = list(range(len(list_in)))
    shuffle(indices)
    index_partitions = [sorted(indices[i::n]) for i in range(n)]
    return [[list_in[i] for i in index_partition] 
            for index_partition in index_partitions]
```

(that is we shuffle the indices then sort them within the partitions)

example:

```
random_partition_preserve_order(list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz'), 3)
# [
#     ['c', 'd', 'g', 'm', 'p', 'r', 'v', 'x', 'y'], 
#     ['b', 'e', 'h', 'k', 'o', 'q', 't', 'u'], 
#     ['a', 'f', 'i', 'j', 'l', 'n', 's', 'z']
# ]
```