# How to generate a random partition from an iterator in Python

Tags: python, random, iterator, partitioning

Given the desired number of partitions, the partitions should be nearly equal in size. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659900/python-slicing-a-list-into-n-nearly-equal-length-partitions) handles the problem for a list. They do not have the random property, but that is [easily added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352737/python-randomly-partition-a-list-into-n-nearly-equal-parts). My problem is, that I have an iterator as input, so `shuffle` does not apply. The reason for that is that I want to randomly partition the nodes of graph. The graph can be very large, so I am looking for a solution that does not just create an intermediate list.

My first idea was to use [`compress()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) with a random number function as selector. But that only works for two partitions.

Comment: "nearly equal in size" — So if there are 1000 nodes and we want to divide it into 5 parts, is 197, 195, 206, 201, 201 acceptable or must it be 200, 200, 200, 200, 200?

Comment: @KennyTM: The first one is acceptable. This is used for k-fold cross-validation, so some deviation is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create k list. When you receive a value, pick a random integer x between 0 and k-1, and put that value into the x-th list.

On average each list will contain N/k elements, but with a standard deviation of √(N * 1/k * (1-1/k)).

```
def random_partition(k, iterable):
  results = [[] for i in range(k)]
  for value in iterable:
    x = random.randrange(k)
    results[x].append(value)
  return results
```

Comment: Can you give a source or explanation for that standard deviation?

Comment: @Space: This is just a binomial distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You're just dealing to various partitions, right?

```
def dealer( iterator, size ):
    for item in iterator
        yield random.randrange( size ), item
```

Won't that get you started by assigning each item to a partition?

Then you can do something like this to make lists.  Maybe not a good thing, but it shows how to use the function.

```
def make_lists( iterator, size ):
    the_lists = []*size
    for partition, item in dealer( iterator, size ):
        the_lists[partition].append(item)
    return the_lists
```

Comment: You could shorten the second part by using groupby, from itertools.

Comment: @wheaties: while true, it's not clear what the partitions are being used for.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the length of lists more uniform by adjusting the weights depending on the number of nodes generated so far in each partition. They'll be roughly equal-length if you pick a function so that the weight is 0 when (number of nodes in partition n) > (number of nodes)/(number of partions), i.e.

weight[i] = max(numNodes/numPartitions - nodesSoFar[i],0)

(The max() is to stop negative weights, which might happen if you have 4 nodes and 3 partitions.)

Then pick a random number from 1 to sum(weights) (or 0 to sum(weights)-1) and pick the partition appropriately.

`compress()` works provided you use a different selector per partition; something like `(x == n for x in random_partition_numbers)` where random_partition_numbers is a generator. You'll need to copy random_partition_numbers for each partition, of course. This design is inherently slower, since it needs to iterate through the list of nodes for each partition.