# How to parallelize a sum calculation in python numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, sum, parallel-processing, scipy

I have a sum that I'm trying to compute, and I'm having difficulty parallelizing the code. The calculation I'm trying to parallelize is kind of complex (it uses both numpy arrays and scipy sparse matrices). It spits out a numpy array, and I want to sum the output arrays from about 1000 calculations. Ideally, I would keep a running sum over all the iterations. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

So far, I've tried using joblib's Parallel function and the pool.map function with python's multiprocessing package. For both of these, I use an inner function that returns a numpy array. These functions return a list, which I convert to a numpy array and then sum over.

However, after the joblib Parallel function completes all iterations, the main program never continues running (it looks like the original job is in a suspended state, using 0% CPU). When I use pool.map, I get memory errors after all the iterations are complete.

Is there a way to simply parallelize a running sum of arrays?

**Edit**: The goal is to do something like the following, except in parallel.

```
def summers(num_iters):

    sumArr = np.zeros((1,512*512)) #initialize sum
    for index in range(num_iters):
        sumArr = sumArr + computation(index) #computation returns a 1 x 512^2 numpy array

    return sumArr
```

Comment: you should try to post a minimal example code. Are you trying to perform a convolution?

Comment: No, I'm not doing a convolution. I'm rotating an image about 1000 times, and I need to sum the result from each rotation. For the pool.map, I'm just using
`outputArr = np.array(pool.map(parloop, range(num_views)))` where `parloop` returns a numpy array.

Comment: Maybe it's already parallel? "since numpy knows you want to do a matrix dot product it can use an optimized implementation obtained as part of "BLAS" (the Basic Linear Algebra Subroutines). ... many architectures now have a BLAS that also takes advantage of a multicore machine. If your numpy/scipy is compiled using one of these, then dot() will be computed in parallel (if this is faster) **without you doing anything**." www.scipy.org/ParallelProgramming

Comment: Also look into `numexpr`: https://code.google.com/p/numexpr/  You tell it the equation you want it to calculate (same as python code, but written as a string), and it takes care of the optimization and multi-threading for you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out how to do parallelize a sum of arrays with multiprocessing, apply_async, and callbacks, so I'm posting this here for other people. I used [the example page for Parallel Python](http://www.parallelpython.com/content/view/17/31/) for the Sum callback class, although I did not actually use that package for implementation. It gave me the idea of using callbacks, though. Here's the simplified code for what I ended up using, and it does what I wanted it to do.

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import thread

class Sum: #again, this class is from ParallelPython's example code (I modified for an array and added comments)
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = np.zeros((1,512*512)) #this is the initialization of the sum
        self.lock = thread.allocate_lock()
        self.count = 0

    def add(self,value):
        self.count += 1
        self.lock.acquire() #lock so sum is correct if two processes return at same time
        self.value += value #the actual summation
        self.lock.release()

def computation(index):
    array1 = np.ones((1,512*512))*index #this is where the array-returning computation goes
    return array1

def summers(num_iters):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8)

    sumArr = Sum() #create an instance of callback class and zero the sum
    for index in range(num_iters):
        singlepoolresult = pool.apply_async(computation,(index,),callback=sumArr.add)

    pool.close()
    pool.join() #waits for all the processes to finish

    return sumArr.value
```

I was also able to get this working using a parallelized map, which was suggested in another answer. I had tried this earlier, but I wasn't implementing it correctly. Both ways work, and I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533318/python-multiprocessing-pool-when-to-use-apply-apply-async-or-map) explains the issue of which method to use (map or apply.async) pretty well. For the map version, you don't need to define the class Sum and the summers function becomes

```
def summers(num_iters):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8)

    outputArr = np.zeros((num_iters,1,512*512)) #you wouldn't have to initialize these
    sumArr = np.zeros((1,512*512))              #but I do to make sure I have the memory

    outputArr = np.array(pool.map(computation, range(num_iters)))
    sumArr = outputArr.sum(0)

    pool.close() #not sure if this is still needed since map waits for all iterations

    return sumArr
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the problem.   Are you just trying to partition a list onto a pool of workers, have them keep a running sum of their computations, and sum the result?

```
#!/bin/env python
import sys
import random
import time
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

numpows = 5
numitems = 25
nprocs = 4

def expensiveComputation( i ):
  time.sleep( random.random() * 10 )
  return np.array([i**j for j in range(numpows)])

def listsum( l ):
  sum = np.zeros_like(l[0])
  for item in l:
    sum = sum + item
  return sum

def partition(lst, n):
  division = len(lst) / float(n)
  return [ lst[int(round(division * i)): int(round(division * (i + 1)))] for i in xrange(n) ]

def myRunningSum( l ):
  sum = np.zeros(numpows)
  for item in l:
     sum = sum + expensiveComputation(item)
  return sum

if __name__ == '__main__':

  random.seed(1)
  data = range(numitems)

  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4,)
  calculations = pool.map(myRunningSum, partition(data,nprocs))

  print 'Answer is:', listsum(calculations)
  print 'Expected answer: ', np.array([25.,300.,4900.,90000.,1763020.])
```

(the partition function coming from [Python: Slicing a list into n nearly-equal-length partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659900/python-slicing-a-list-into-n-nearly-equal-length-partitions/2660034#2660034) )

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I wanted to keep a running sum over multiple iterations, without summing over any lists at the end. I'm rotating an image about 1000 times, and I need to sum the result of a calculation from each rotation. I think I figured out how to do it and posted it as an answer.

Comment: Is one array returned per processor really such a big deal?  There's _way_ less overhead this way.