# Parallel CPU sum in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpoolexecutor

I have a loop for finding several sum:

```
for t in reversed(range(len(inputs))):
  dy = np.copy(ps[t])
  dy[targets[t]] -= 1 
  dWhy += np.dot(dy, hs[t].T)
  dby += dy
```

Input value is too big and i must to make it parallel. So I so I converted the loop to a separate function. I've tried to use ThreadPoolExecutor, but result time is slow compared to the sequential algorithm.

That's my minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
import concurrent.futures
import time, random 

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import threading

#parameters
dWhy = np.random.sample(300)
dby = np.random.sample(300)

def Func(ps, targets, hs,  t):
  global dWhy, dby
  dy = np.copy(ps[t])
  dWhy += np.dot(dy, hs[t].T)
  dby += dy

  return dWhy, dby

if __name__ == '__main__':    

    ps = np.random.sample(100000)
    targets = np.random.sample(100000)
    hs = np.random.sample(100000)

    start = time.time()

    for t in range(100000):
        dy = np.copy(ps[t])
        dWhy += np.dot(dy, hs[t].T)
        dby += dy

    finish = time.time()
    print("One thread: ")
    print(finish-start)

    dWhy = np.random.sample(300)
    dby = np.random.sample(300)
    start = time.time()

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        args = ((ps, targets, hs,  t) for t in range(100000))
        for out1, out2  in executor.map(lambda p: Func(*p), args):
            dWhy, dby = out1, out2

    finish = time.time()
    print("Multithreads time: ")
    print(finish-start)
```

On my PC One thread-time ~ 3s, Multithreads time ~ 1 minute.

Comment: Use ProcessPool for CPU bound operations. ThreadPools only speed up I/O bound operations.

Comment: @Neil could you show me some example for my task? I have KeyError 0 with ProcessPool

Comment: Please paste code where you call the function

Comment: In many cases it could be relevant to just use boardcasting. Since numpy is fast enogh when you do perform loops. Could you provide the dimensions (.shape) for each of your objects?

Comment: Please post a minimum working example.

Comment: Still looks like a numpy broadcasting problem more than anything else. np.dot(ps,hs) takes 0.000082 seconds on my laptop, with ps and hs being shape (100000,) and the same for the sum np.sum(ps)

Comment: @PeterMølgaardPallesen is that mean i can't to speed up of algorithm width numpy? In general i must show parallel implementation with speed up results...

Comment: Just saying that parallization typically can give you a speed up of 2-16 times dependeling on the problems and your availiable hardware. As I pointed out not during proper broadcasting and during looping instead can result in a speed slowdown much larger.  For example the code you stated which takes 3 seconds to perform takes 0.000164 to perform by using boardcasting a speed up of over 10000 times.

Comment: @PeterMølgaardPallesen i'm beginner in Python so i don't understand. Can you give me some example of identical operations with broadcasting and without?

Comment: Replace: for t in range(100000):
        dy = np.copy(ps[t])
        dWhy += np.dot(dy, hs[t].T)
        dby += dy 

with dWhy += np.dot(dy, ps) and dby += np.sum(ds). Which performs the same but take 10000 times shorter time. Potentially start reading with something like this.https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.05-computation-on-arrays-broadcasting.html in general the strength of numpy is that you by using broadcasting can achive C-speed for most problems

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068478/how-to-parallelize-a-sum-calculation-in-python-numpy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parallelize a sum calculation in python numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068478/how-to-parallelize-a-sum-calculation-in-python-numpy)

Answer (score 0):

Turn the lambda into a named function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider impliment it with broadcasting instead:

```
import numpy as np
dWhy = np.random.sample(300)
dby = np.random.sample(300)

ps = np.random.sample(100000)
targets = np.random.sample(100000)
hs = np.random.sample(100000)

dWhy += np.dot(ps,hs)
dby += np.sum(ps)
```

When running it 20000 times faster

```
timer = time.time()
for i in range(20000):
    dWhy += np.dot(ps,hs)
    dby += np.sum(ps)
print(time.time()-timer)
>>3.2034592628479004
print(time.time()-timer)/20000)
>>0.00016017296314239503
```