# How can I split an integer into a list of n length evenly in Python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to be able to split an integer into a list of n-length evenly.

For example n = 4,

```
12 -> [0, 0, 1, 2]
1234 -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
12345 -> [1, 2, 3, 45]
123456 -> [1, 2, 34, 56]
1234567 -> [1, 23, 45, 67]
12345678 -> 12, 34, 56, 78]
123456789 -> [12, 34, 56, 789]
```

I'm sure I went overkill with the number of examples I have given, but it'll help get the point across.

The code that I have used in the past to split items into lists is:

```
def split(s, chunk_size):
    a = zip(*[s[i::chunk_size] for i in range(chunk_size)])
    return [''.join(t) for t in a]
```

but this code only breaks into n-chunks. (Code from StackOverflow, I don't remember the exact post, sorry).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def split(seq, n):
    """Partitions `seq` into `n` successive slices of roughly equal size.

    The sizes of each yielded slice shall differ by at most one.
    """
    q, r = divmod(len(seq), n)
    start = 0

    for i in range(n):
        size = q + (i < r)
        yield seq[start : start + size]
        start += size
```

It basically works the same way as [this popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464), except it evenly distributes the remainder into each of the *n* slices.

Unfortunately, this will distribute towards the head of the list. To tweak it for your case, you need to change `size = q + (i < r)` to something like:

```
size = q + (i >= (n - r))
```

With this change, the following:

```
print(list(split('1234', 4)))
print(list(split('12345', 4)))
print(list(split('123456', 4)))
print(list(split('1234567', 4)))
print(list(split('12345678', 4)))
print(list(split('123456789', 4)))
```

prints:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
['1', '2', '3', '45']
['1', '2', '34', '56']
['1', '23', '45', '67']
['12', '34', '56', '78']
['12', '34', '56', '789']
```

Comment: When I use the function and copied the prints I get this as my results:    ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 
['12', '3', '4', '5'], 
['12', '34', '5', '6'], 
['12', '34', '56', '7'], 
['12', '34', '56', '78'], 
['123', '45', '67', '89'].

Comment: @AustinB Please read the answer in full before just copy+pasting.

Comment: Ah thanks, I am quite tired right now and just needed to quickly finish a portion of my project. Thanks for the help.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2659900/6732794) older, more popular, similar question was brought to my attention just recently. In particular, this answer here is more or less the same in spirit as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2660138/6732794) in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Variant on Ahsan's answer that should distribute to the remainder across the end of the sequence correctly:

```
from itertools import accumulate

def split(s, parts):
    s = str(s)
    r, rem = divmod(len(s), parts)
    norem = parts - rem
    counts = [r]*norem + [r+1]*rem
    # Prepend 0 to counts only for accumulate to start from 0
    return [s[start:start+cnt] for start, cnt in zip(accumulate([0] + counts), counts)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer has its advantage, but I did it in a more straightforward way:

```
def chunk(s, n):
    return [s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s), n)]

def split(s0, numberOfChunks):
    s = ('0' * max(0, numberOfChunks - len(s0))) + s0
    sizeOfChunk = len(s) / numberOfChunks
    numberOfSmallChunks = numberOfChunks - len(s) % numberOfChunks
    return chunk(s[:numberOfSmallChunks * sizeOfChunk], sizeOfChunk) +
           chunk(s[sizeOfChunk*numberOfSmallChunks:], sizeOfChunk+1)
```

Answer (score -1):

sorry - for faulty code
It is working according to the spec

```
def split(s, list_size):
    s = str(s)
    assert len(s) >= list_size, "assertion failed"
    r, rem = divmod(len(s), list_size)
    lst = []
    for i in range(list_size):
        lst.append(s[i*r:(i+1)*r])
    for j in range(rem):
        lst[-(j+1)] += s[list_size + j]
    return lst
```

Comment: This will fail with `1234567` case.

Comment: That shoves the entire remainder into the final element, does it not? The examples show that the remainder spread out; 7 items split 4 ways produces elements of length 1, 2, 2, 2, not 1, 1, 1, 4.

Comment: Now the bug has been fixed

Comment: Getting an odd amount of 4's being produced into the lists, and numbers seem to be getting "shuffled": ['1', '2', '3', '4']
['1', '2', '3', '44']
['1', '2', '35', '44']
['1', '26', '35', '44']
['12', '34', '56', '78']
['12', '34', '56', '784']