# Iterating over (X) elements at a time to end of index [3]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, iteration

I'm looking for a Pythonic way to iterate through a dataframe's index such that I can chunk a computationally heavy list into a series of smaller lists to run. The output of each chunk will be appended to a CSV in order to avoid resource limits.

For example, if I have some list who's length is prime, I'd like to split that list into a number of lists of relatively equal length, run the computations against that set, and and append the output of that set to a CSV. Rinse and repeat all the way down the index of the dataframe until all of the rows have been run against.

e.g.

1. Run some function on the first 10,000 - store in csv
2. Run on the 10,001 - 20,000 row - store in csv
3. .....
4. Run through row 111,376 - store in csv
5. end.

Comment: Have you tried [iterating over slices of the frame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1335456/364696)?

Comment: If you are working on `pandas.DataFrame` and worried about the resource limits, you can try passing `iterator=True` when you read your csv, and do `yourDF.get_chunk(n)` where n is your desired number of rows.

Comment: Thanks to all! @ShadowRanger I was able to use the Chunker object classification to iterate over slices successfully.

Comment: @Chris chunking on the way in helped immensely, I'm now below 50% of my memory usage running this script. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @ShadowRanger:

Have you tried iterating over slices of the frame? -
[Iteration over list slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335392/iteration-over-list-slices/1335456#1335456)