# Splitting a list based on a delimiter word

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list containing various string values. I want to split the list whenever I see `WORD`. The result will be a list of lists (which will be the sublists of original list) containing exactly one instance of the `WORD` I can do this using a loop but is there a *more pythonic* way to do achieve this ?

Example = `['A', 'WORD', 'B' , 'C' , 'WORD' , 'D']`

result = `[['A'], ['WORD','B','C'],['WORD','D']]`

This is what I have tried but it  actually does not achieve what I want since it will put `WORD` in a different list that it should be in:

```
def split_excel_cells(delimiter, cell_data):

    result = []

    temp = []

    for cell in cell_data:
        if cell == delimiter:
            temp.append(cell)
            result.append(temp)
            temp = []
        else:
            temp.append(cell)

    return result
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would use a generator:

```
def group(seq, sep):
    g = []
    for el in seq:
        if el == sep:
            yield g
            g = []
        g.append(el)
    yield g

ex = ['A', 'WORD', 'B' , 'C' , 'WORD' , 'D']
result = list(group(ex, 'WORD'))
print(result)
```

This prints

```
[['A'], ['WORD', 'B', 'C'], ['WORD', 'D']]
```

The code accepts any iterable, and produces an iterable (which you don't *have* to flatten into a list if you don't want to).

Comment: Note that if u want to exclude the delimiter from the results, u can add continue statement inside the if statement in the `group` function.

Comment: Note that if you exclude the stop-word, you would be yielding a empty list if the stop-word is at the end of your input

Answer (score 41):

```
import itertools

lst = ['A', 'WORD', 'B' , 'C' , 'WORD' , 'D']
w = 'WORD'

spl = [list(y) for x, y in itertools.groupby(lst, lambda z: z == w) if not x]
```

this creates a splitted list without delimiters, which looks more logical to me:

```
[['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D']]
```

If you insist on delimiters to be included, this should do the trick:

```
spl = [[]]
for x, y in itertools.groupby(lst, lambda z: z == w):
    if x: spl.append([])
    spl[-1].extend(y)
```

Comment: Strongly suggest to use this answer as it's much pythonic with the builtin `itertools` module!

Comment: Unfortunately, the second version gives incorrect result if delimeter is repeated.

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'

Answer (score 4):

- @NPE's solution looks very pythonic to me. This is another one using `itertools`:
- `izip` is specific to python 2.7. Replace `izip` with `zip` to work in python 3

```py
from itertools import izip, chain
example = ['A', 'WORD', 'B' , 'C' , 'WORD' , 'D']
indices = [i for i,x in enumerate(example) if x=="WORD"]
pairs = izip(chain([0], indices), chain(indices, [None]))
result = [example[i:j] for i, j in pairs]
```

- This code is mainly based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198512/split-a-list-into-parts-based-on-a-set-of-indexes-in-python#1198876).

Comment: Thanks I also attempted to split based on indices but wasnt sure how to pair them up. This is a very nice way.

Answer (score 3):

**Given**

```
import more_itertools as mit


iterable = ["A", "WORD", "B" , "C" , "WORD" , "D"]
pred = lambda x: x == "WORD"
```

**Code**

```
list(mit.split_before(iterable, pred))
# [['A'], ['WORD', 'B', 'C'], ['WORD', 'D']]
```

[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) is a third-party library installable via `> pip install more_itertools`.

See also [`split_at`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_at) and [`split_after`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_after).