# Pythonic way to split list into parts by conditionaly-given delimeter

Tags: python, functional-programming

I have a list and I want to split it into parts moslty like `str.split()` works for strings with the following differences:

1. The delimiter is given by predicate. If predicate is `True` for element of the list, this element is considered as a delimeter.
2. I want to keep the delimeter in the resulting lists.

For example:

```
split_by_predicate([0, "One", 1, 2, 3, 
                    "Two", 4, 5, 6, 7, "Three", "Four"],
                    predicate=lambda x: isinstance(x, str))
```

should give me

```
[[0], ["One", 1, 2, 3], ["Two", 4, 5, 6, 7], ["Three"], ["Four"]]
```

I can write the following code:

```
def split_by_predicate(it, predicate):
    lst = []
    cur = []
    for element in it:
       if predicate(element):
          lst.append(cur)
          cur = []
       cur.append(element)
    lst.append(cur)
    return lst
```

But I find it not elegant and not Pythonic. A similar approach is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15358005/3025981) (using generators).

I tried to figure out some kind of `itertools`-based solution like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15358422/3025981), but they don't work well if the delimeter is repeated (like in my example).

Are there any ideas how to do it in more functional style than my current code?

Answer (score 5):

You can simplify your function to this:

```
def split_by_predicate(it, predicate):
    lst = [[]]
    for element in it:
        if predicate(element):
            lst.append([])
        lst[-1].append(element)
    return lst
```

Or this ( with skiped appending empty list on first iteration ):

```
def split_by_predicate(it, predicate):
    lst = [[]]
    for i, element in enumerate(it):
        if predicate(element) and i:
            lst.append([])
        lst[-1].append(element)
    return lst
```

Comment: It will have an empty `[]` if `it` consists an `str` as first element.

Comment: @mshsayem `',one,1,2,3'.split(',')` - will give empty string at first element. I don't think that it is a problem

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
def split_by_predicate(it, predicate):
  o = []
  for i in it:
    if predicate(i) or len(o) == 0:
      o += [[i]]
    else:
      o[-1] += [i]
  return o
```

Output:

```
>>> split_by_predicate([0, 'One', 1, 2, 3, 'Two', 4, 5, 6, 7, 'Three', 'Four'], lambda x: isinstance(x,str))
[[0], ['One', 1, 2, 3], ['Two', 4, 5, 6, 7], ['Three'], ['Four']]
```