# Python split list by multiple elements and conditions

Tags: python, list, split, conditional-statements

I am very new to python and getting stuck in list splitting even referring to many examples in stackoverflow. What can I do if I want to split a list with the following conditions?

Task 1. Split the list like this once the items in "wordlist" were found in "datalist" collected.

```
Wordlist = ["Time", "date", "place",....]

output = ["A","B"]["Time","C","D","E"]["Date",.....]
```

Task 2. Once a specific item was found, the list would be split following by the specific word and n items included, then continue to loop over the dlist. e.g.

word, n = no. of item followed

Time, 1

Date, 2

place, 1

....

input:

```
datalist = ["A","B", "N", "K" , "R", "Time", "2230" , "C" , "Date" , '12/05', "E" , "F", "R", "F", "K" ,"Place", "XXXXXX", "H", "I" , "J" ]

wordlist = ["Time", "Date", "Place"]

n = [1,2,1]
```

output:

```
newlist = [["A","B", "N", "K" , "R"] ,["Time", "2230"],[ "C"], [ "Date" , '12/05',"E"][ "F", "R", "F", "K" ], ["Place", "XXXXXX"], ["H", "I","J"] ]
```

This is my referred example solving task-1 partially while not for task-2:
[Python spliting a list based on a delimiter word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357830/python-spliting-a-list-based-on-a-delimiter-word)

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: what have you tried that isn't working? also your expected inputs and outputs aren't 100% consistent with the wording of what you ask.

Comment: Sorry, the inputs and outputs are fixed just now, sorry for my typo. @aaron

Comment: Make sure to see my edit. there was an edge case fail.

Comment: Noticed the edge case fail, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the approach in the other answer you linked, I'd direct you to using a generator for a more general purpose solution.

```
def split_list(wordlist, splitwords = {}):
    out = []
    worditer = iter(wordlist)
    for word in worditer:
        if word in splitwords: #potentially yield previous non-keyword list and build keyword list
            if out: #yield non-keyword list
                yield out
            out = [word] #start new list with keyword
            try:
                for _ in range(splitwords[word]): #add *n* more words after keyword
                    out.append(next(worditer))
            except StopIteration: #not enough items after keyword
                pass
            yield out #yield keyword list
            out = [] #reset accumulator
        else:
            out.append(word) #grow non-keyword list
    if out: #yield trailing non-keyword list
        yield out

datalist = ["A","B", "N", "K" , "R", "Time", "2230" , "C" , "Date" , '12/05', "E" , "F", "R", "F", "K" ,"Place", "XXXXXX", "H", "I" , "J" ]
splitwords = {"Time": 1, "Date": 2, "Place": 1}

newlist = list(split_list(datalist, splitwords))
print(newlist)
```

Comment: this actually has some edge case fails... imma edit real quick

Comment: see edit for edge case of starting with a keyword or keyword lists backing up to one another.

Comment: Thank you so much! it's helpful to learn from your detailed markdown! @Aaron

Comment: @Sth_paul really good code is usually at least 50% comments. If you come back to this in a year, you'll only understand what you did if you comment your code. If there are any things I did you don't understand please ask.

Comment: will keep commenting as much as I can as a beginner. I guess you just give a good tip for me again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A one-line solution for task 1:

```
[datalist[:datalist.index(wordlist[0])]] + [datalist[datalist.index(wordlist[i]):datalist.index(wordlist[i+1])] for i in range(len(wordlist)-1)] + [datalist[datalist.index(wordlist[-1]):]]
```

which `outputs`:

```
[['A', 'B', 'N', 'K', 'R'], ['Time', '2230'], ['C'], ['Date', '12/05', 'E'], ['F', 'R', 'F', 'K'], ['Place', 'XXXXXX'], ['H', 'I', 'J']]
```

---

Task 2:

```
sol = []
i = 0
s = 0
while i < len(datalist):
    if datalist[i] in wordlist:
        cs = n[wordlist.index(datalist[i])]
        print(cs)
        sol += [datalist[s:i], datalist[i:i+cs+1]]
        i += cs
        s = i + 1
    i += 1

sol.append(datalist[s:])
```

which `outputs`:

```
[['A', 'B', 'N', 'K', 'R'], ['Time', '2230'], ['C'], ['Date', '12/05', 'E'], ['F', 'R', 'F', 'K'], ['Place', 'XXXXXX'], ['H', 'I', 'J']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 datalist = ['A', 'B', 'N', 'K', 'R', 'Time', '2230', 'C', 'Date', '12/05', 
'E', 'F', 'R', 'F', 'K', 'Place', 'XXXXXX', 'H', 'I', 'J']
```

Getting the words :
    `>>> [dl for dl in datalist if dl.isalpha() and len(dl) > 1]`
    `['Time', 'Date', 'Place', 'XXXXXX']`

Getting the characters is the same as getting the words the only difference is that the length should be equal to 1.

Getting the numbers :
    `>>> [dl for dl in datalist if dl.isnumeric()]`
    `['2230']`

Getting the dates:
    `>>> [dl for dl in datalist if '/' in dl]`
    `['12/05']`
That solution is a little dumb. For a more refined solution I suggest the use of the re module.

You can then pack the results il a list to get the result you desire.