# Python groupby to split list by delimiter

Tags: python, list, split, delimiter

I am pretty new to Python (3.6) and struggling to understand itertools groupby.
I've got the following list containing integers:

```
    list1 = [1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0]
```

But the list could also be much longer and the '0' doesn't have to appear after every pair of numbers. It can also be after 3, 4 or more numbers. My goal is to split this list into sublists where the '0' is used as a delimiter and doesn't appear in any of these sublists.

```
    list2 = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

A similar problem has been solved here already:
[Python spliting a list based on a delimiter word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357830/python-spliting-a-list-based-on-a-delimiter-word)
Answer 2 seemed to help me a lot but unfortunately it only gave me a TypeError.

```
    import itertools as it

    list1 = [1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0]

    list2 = [list(group) for key, group in it.groupby(list1, lambda x: x == 0) if not key]

    print(list2)
```

> File "H:/Python/work/ps0001/example.py", line 13, in 
>       list2 = [list(group) for key, group in it.groupby(list, lambda x: x == '0') if not key]
>
> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

I would appreciate any help and be very happy to finally understand groupby.

Comment: You should never name your custom list as "list" since that is a keyword. Use "mylist" / "onelist" etc.

Comment: `list` is a reserved keyword. Rename `list = [1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0]` to `list1` or whatever.

Comment: thanks! I changed it and will Keep it in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were checking for "0" (str) but you only have 0 (int) in your list. Also, you were using `list` as a variable name for your first list, which is a keyword in Python.

```
from itertools import groupby

list1 = [1, 2, 0, 2, 7, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0]
list2 = [list(group) for key, group in groupby(list1, lambda x: x == 0) if not key]

print(list2)
```

This should give you:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 7, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: It gives me `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` again. Could the expression `list(group)` be a problem?

Comment: Did you change the name of your first list to something other than "list"?

Comment: yes, I changed it to list1 as in the OP. I tried your example by just copy and past and it still gave me that error.

Comment: @schuph You'll have to change the reference of the list variable when you pass it to groupby as well. And, it seems to work for me: https://repl.it/@sahaysid/GroupByToSplitListOnDelim

Comment: What do you mean by changig reference of the list variable? Obviously your example works just fine but in my IPython console it gives me a TypeError referencing to this line `list2 = [list(group) for key, group in groupby(list1, lambda x: x == 0) if not key]`.

Comment: By change the reference to the list variable in the call to groupby I meant change it from `list` to `list1` in your third line where you're assigning to `list2`.

Comment: So, your example is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot for that! But it looks like Spyder/IPython doesn't like the expression `list(group)` because that must be the reason for my TypeError. I have just no idea why...

Comment: That's really strange. Never encountered that problem before!

Comment: Restarting Spyder did the job! :D

Comment: It probably had your definition of `list` still in memory.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you need to change `lambda x: x == '0'` to `lambda x: x == 0`, since your working with a list of `int`, not a list of `str`.

Since others have shown how to improve your solution with `itertools.groupby`, you can also do this task with no libraries:

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0]
>>> zeroes = [-1] + [i for i, e in enumerate(list1) if e == 0]
>>> result = [list1[zeroes[i] + 1: zeroes[i + 1]] for i in range(len(zeroes) - 1)]
>>> print(result)
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for this:

```
>>> import ast 
>>> your_list = [1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0]
>>> a_list = str(your_list).replace(', 0,', '], [').replace(', 0]', ']')
>>> your_result = ast.literal_eval(a_list)
>>> your_result
([1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5])
>>> your_result[0]
[1, 2]
>>>
```

Or a single line solution:

```
ast.literal_eval(str(your_list).replace(', 0,', '], [').replace(', 0]', ']'))
```

Comment: Throwing Regex at everything is almost always a bad idea/design when there are native tools available. Regex has it's own ground. Also, if the list grows bigger, changing list to string, applying Regex, evaluating again will cost very badly.

Comment: This is very Rube Goldberg and very brittle. For example, if the list contains a sublist, this will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that within a Loop as depicted in the commented Snippet below:

```
list1       = [1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0]
tmp,result  = ([],[])   # tmp HOLDS A TEMPORAL LIST :: result => RESULT

for i in list1:
    if not i:
        # CURRENT VALUE IS 0 SO WE BUILD THE SUB-LIST
        result.append(tmp)
        # RE-INITIALIZE THE tmp VARIABLE
        tmp = []
    else:
        # SINCE CURRENT VALUE IS NOT 0, WE POPULATE THE tmp LIST
        tmp.append(i)

print(result) # [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Effectively:

```
list1       = [1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0]
tmp,result  = ([],[])   # HOLDS A TEMPORAL LIST

for i in list1:
    if not i:
        result.append(tmp); tmp = []
    else:
        tmp.append(i)

print(result) # [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `join` and then split by `0`

```
lst = [1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0]

lst_string = "".join([str(x) for x in lst])
lst2 = lst_string.split('0')
lst3 = [list(y) for y in lst2]
lst4 = [list(map(int, z)) for z in lst3]
print(lst4)
```

Running on my console:

[image]

Comment: You'll have to convert back to int, the elements in the list are strings.

Comment: It gives me `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` again. Could the Expression `list(y)` be a problem?

Comment: DO NOT USE `list` as your variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Use zip to return a tuple of lists and convert them to list later on

```
>>> a
[1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0]
>>> a[0::3]
[1, 2, 4]
>>> a[1::3]
[2, 3, 5]
>>> zip(a[0::3],a[1::3])
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
>>> [list(i) for i in zip(a[0::3],a[1::3])]
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
```