# Split list elements in Python?

Tags: python, group-by

I have a list,

```
['t', 'p', 'k', 'F', 'p', 'l', 'v', 'F']
```

and I want to group the elements by the 'F', where the 'F' is the end of the group, so it `splits` the list into separate groups.

Like this:

```
['t', 'p', 'k'] ['p', 'l', 'v']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python spliting a list based on a delimiter word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357830/python-spliting-a-list-based-on-a-delimiter-word)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with a `key` function:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = ['t', 'p', 'k', 'F', 'p', 'l', 'v', 'F']

result = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(l, key=lambda x: x != 'F') if k]
>>> result
[['t', 'p', 'k'], ['p', 'l', 'v']]
```

Another way is with string operations:

```
result = [list(x) for x in ''.join(l).split('F') if x]
>>> result
[['t', 'p', 'k'], ['p', 'l', 'v']]
```

Note that both solutions above will include any trailing items that follow the final `'F'`. Not sure if that is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

This program assumes that your list elements are always single characters.  If that isn't true, you would need to work directly on the list.  I convert to a string to use the convenient str.split method, then convert each substring back into a list.

```
inp = ['t', 'p', 'k', 'F', 'p', 'l', 'v', 'F']
print(inp)
groups_as_strings = "".join(inp).split("F")
out = [list(g) for g in groups_as_strings if g]
print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way.

```
lst = ['t', 'p', 'k', 'F', 'p', 'l', 'v', 'F']

list(map(list, ''.join(lst).split('F')[:-1]))

# [['t', 'p', 'k'], ['p', 'l', 'v']]
```

Comment: More explicit: `[list(i) for i in ''.join(LL).split('F') if i]`

Comment: What if the elements are more than single character?

Comment: @PeterWood, choose another solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple but easy to follow solution:

```
new_list = []
tmp_list = []
for i in letter_list:
  if i == 'F':
    if tmp_list:
      new_list.append(tmp_list)
      tmp_list = []
    continue
  tmp_list.append(i)

print(new_list)
```

Note that this assumes empty lists (consecutive F's) should be ignored, but that's easy to remove.