# Split in a list by specific element to get a list of lists Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Input

```
['~', 'n1', 'n2', ..., 'nn', '~', 'k1', 'k2', ..., 'kn', '~']
```

Desired output:

```
[['n1', 'n2', ..., 'nn'],['k1', 'k2', ..., 'kn']]
```

I have seen itertools groupby but cannot get it to work. Any help would be appreciated. Also the ... is not actually in the list, just saying there are more elements in between

Comment: If you're splitting on `'~'`, shouldn't the list start and end with an empty list `[]`? Should empty lists not be included in the result?

Comment: no empty lists in the result, just simply what I said in the output

Comment: Related: [Python spliting a list based on a delimiter word](//stackoverflow.com/q/15357830) (Similar question, but includes the separator elements in the output)

Comment: @Aran-Fey this answer answers perfectly, that said: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15358422/6451573, in the first part (even if it's not the output that OP needs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `groupby` method is the best one.

group using the key function `item != '~'`, and filter on the key being `True` (when `x=='~'`, the key function returns `False`, the `if k` condition filters that out)

```
import itertools

lst = ['~', 'n1', 'n2', 'nn', '~', 'k1', 'k2', 'kn', '~']

result = [list(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(lst,lambda x : x!='~') if k]
```

result:

```
[['n1', 'n2', 'nn'], ['k1', 'k2', 'kn']]
```

note that you have to force iteration on issued groups, since `groupby` returns iterables (just in case you just need to iterate on them again)

If you have empty strings, it's even simpler: no need for `lambda`, rely on the truthfullness of the values and use `bool` operator:

```
lst = ['', 'n1', 'n2', 'nn', '', 'k1', 'k2', 'kn', '']

result = [list(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(lst,bool) if k]
```

Comment: Ok great, follow up question. What if the '~'s were instead empty strings ''