# Tokenize a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I like to tokenize a list using a list item as a delimiter.

Is there is a pythonic way to do this or do I have to write something on my own.

```
Data=['Label',23,'NORM','|','RESP',1.256,None,'|','','','|','RELV','','']
SubList = TokenizeList (Data,Delim='|')
```

printing SubList would result in

```
[ ['Label',23,'NORM'] , ['RESP',1.256,None] , ['',''] , ['RELV','',''] ]
```

Comment: Can those words contain *any* character?

Comment: You mean the delimiter or the list items? The original list can contain anything, the delimite is a character like in .split()

Comment: I mean the items. Can they contain a space for example?

Comment: Yes, they probably can, but a space (or a number of spaces) is here like having an empty string, so I can replace them in advance

Comment: Can they contain only numbers and string or other objects as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python splitting a list based on a delimiter word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357830/python-splitting-a-list-based-on-a-delimiter-word)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def group_by_sep(items, sep='|'):
    inner_list = []
    for item in items:
        if item == sep:
            yield inner_list
            inner_list = []
        else:
            inner_list.append(item)
    if inner_list:
        yield inner_list


Data=['Label',23,'NORM','|','RESP',1.256,None,'|','','','|','RELV','','','|','|','now','|']

SubList = list(group_by_sep(Data, '|'))
print(SubList)
# [['Label', 23, 'NORM'], ['RESP', 1.256, None], ['', ''], ['RELV', '', ''], [], ['now']]
```

---

Note that a `itertools.groupby` approach can be used here, but it is not equivalent to the above and offers less control over the exact behavior:

```
import itertools


def group_by_sep2(items, sep='|'):
    yield from (
        list(g)
        for k, g in itertools.groupby(items, key=lambda x: x == sep)
        if not k)


SubList2 = list(group_by_sep2(Data, '|'))
print(SubList2)
# [['Label', 23, 'NORM'], ['RESP', 1.256, None], ['', ''], ['RELV', '', ''], ['now']]
```

It is missing the empty `list` between two consecutive separators.

Additionally, it is not as efficient as the direct method from above:

```
%timeit list(group_by_sep(Data))
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.47 µs per loop
%timeit list(group_by_sep2(Data))
# 100 loops, best of 3: 4.01 µs per loop

%timeit list(group_by_sep(Data * 1000))
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.33 ms per loop
%timeit list(group_by_sep2(Data * 1000))
# 100 loops, best of 3: 2.83 ms per loop

%timeit list(group_by_sep(Data * 1000000))
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.67 s per loop
%timeit list(group_by_sep2(Data * 1000000))
# 100 loops, best of 3: 3.22 s per loop
```

And the benchmarks indicate that the direct approach is ~2x to ~3x faster.

(EDITED to write it all as generators and included more edge cases)

Comment: Hey, we both thought the same logic ;-)

Comment: @shaikmoeed there isn't much else you can write to solve the problem ;-)

Comment: Our approach matches one of the `zen of python` rules I,e., *Explicit is better than implicit*. (+1) for adding timings.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> Data=['Label',23,'NORM','|','RESP',1.256,None,'|','','','|','RELV','','']
>>> [list(g) for k,g in groupby(Data,key=lambda x:x == '|') if not k]
[['Label', 23, 'NORM'], ['RESP', 1.256, None], ['', ''], ['RELV', '', '']]
```

You can make a function of course:

```
def splitList(sequence, delimiter):
    return [list(g) for k, g in groupby(sequence, key = lambda x: x == delimiter) if not k]
>>> splitList(sequence = Data, delimiter = '|')
[['Label', 23, 'NORM'], ['RESP', 1.256, None], ['', ''], ['RELV', '', '']]
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted because it's the only one which is really *pythonic*, as asked by the user

Comment: While you can use `itertools.groupby()` for this, it may not be the most efficient approach here

Comment: It is also behaving differently (and it is hard to adapt) if two consecutive separators are found.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, which is simple and straight (Pythonic as well),

```
def tokenize_list(array, sep='|'):
    result = []
    _temp = []
    for el in array:
        if el == sep:
            result.append(_temp)
            _temp = []
        else:
            _temp.append(el)
    if _temp: # Finally append list after for-loop, to store last vlaues present in _temp if exists.
        result.append(_temp) 
    return result
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> data = ['Label',23,'NORM','|','RESP',1.256,None,'|','','','|','RELV','','', '|']
>>> tokenize_list(data)
[['Label', 23, 'NORM'], ['RESP', 1.256, None], ['', ''], ['RELV', '', '']]
```

Comment: if `Data` ends with `|` this will not work correctly (adds last inner `list` twice)

Comment: @norok2 Thanks. Edited the answer, to handle that case.