# How to split a list into sublists that begin with the delimiting character?

Tags: python, list, split

- I would like to split a list into sublists that begin with the delimiting character

  - The delimiting character must be kept
  - The delimiting character must be the first character of each sublist

Example:

```
delimiter = "x" 
input = ["x","a","x","x",1,2,3,"a","a","x","e"]
output = [["x","a"], ["x"], ["x",1,2,3,"a","a"], ["x","e"]]
```

- In addition to the solutions below, see [Python splitting a list based on a delimiter word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357830/python-splitting-a-list-based-on-a-delimiter-word)

  - The question is similar, but the expected output is slightly different. For instance, the top solution there, returns and empty list at index 0.

Answer (score 5):

Step 1: Find the indices where the `variable` occurs in your list:

```
idx = [ix for ix, val in enumerate(input) if val==variable]
```

Step 2: Generate sub-lists using list slicing:

```
res = [input[i:j] for i,j in zip(idx, idx[1:]+[len(input)])]
```

**Output**

```
print(res)
# [['x', 'a'], ['x'], ['x', 1, 2, 3, 'a', 'a'], ['x', 'e']]
```

Comment: do you think it could be done as a dictionary where "x" is the key?

Comment: And what would be the value of key "x"?

Comment: @RostyKoryaha Dictionary keys are unique, there can be only a single `'x'` key. What would your expected output look like?

Comment: empty string ""

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I don't get the use case of that.

Comment: @RostyKoryaha Do *you* think it can be done with a dictionary? A dictionary is for efficiently looking up the value for any given key. If you only have one key, a dictionary would not be useful (in that case you can just use a variable or two). Now maybe you can use something else as the key, but you'll need to come up with some sequence of steps which include "now I store this value in the dictionary with this key", "now I look up the value for this key in the dictionary" and/or "now I remove the value for this key from the dictionary" (those are the main dictionary operations).

Answer (score 2):

- `input` is a python method, don't use it as a variable name
- This solution will also work if the first characters in the list are not the delimiter

  - Given: `['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'a', 'x', 'x', 1, 2, 3, 'a', 'a', 'x', 'e', 'x']`
  - Returned: `[['a', 'b', 'c'],  ['x', 'a'], ['x'], ['x', 1, 2, 3, 'a', 'a'], ['x', 'e'], ['x']]`

```py
from typing import List  # for type annotations


def sublist_by_delimiter(flat_list: list, delimiter: str) -> List[list]:
    result = list()  # main list
    chunk = list()  # inner list to 
    len_flat_list = len(flat_list)
    for i, v in enumerate(flat_list, 1):  # iterate through t, begin enumerating at 1
        if (v == delimiter) & (i != 1):  # except for the first delimiter 
            result.append(chunk)  # append chunk to result
            chunk = [v]  # create new chunk beginning with v
            if i == len_flat_list:  # if the last value in the list is delimiter
                result.append(chunk)
        elif (i == len_flat_list):  # for the last list in lines
            chunk.append(v)  # append that line to inner
            result.append(chunk)  # append chunk to result
        else:
            chunk.append(v)  # append each v to chunk where v isn't delimiter
            
    return result
            

t = ['x', 'a', 'x', 'x', 1, 2, 3, 'a', 'a', 'x', 'e', 'x']  # an extra x has been added at the end for testing
delim = 'x'
sublist_by_delimiter(t, delim)
[['x', 'a'], ['x'], ['x', 1, 2, 3, 'a', 'a'], ['x', 'e'], ['x']]
```

### Using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

- From python 3.7, `dicts` are guaranteed to be ordered based on insertion, so `dict.values()` will be ordered when returned.
- This solution is a great choice for anyone wanting to have a dictionary of the segments

  - Change `return list(dd.values())` to `return dd`
- This solution will also work if the first characters in the list are not the delimiter

  - Given: `['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'a', 'x', 'x', 1, 2, 3, 'a', 'a', 'x', 'e', 'x']`
  - Returned: `[['a', 'b', 'c'],  ['x', 'a'], ['x'], ['x', 1, 2, 3, 'a', 'a'], ['x', 'e'], ['x']]`

```py
from collection import defaultdict

def sublist_by_delimiter(flat_list: list, delimiter: str) -> List[list]:
    dd = defaultdict(list)
    counter = 0
    for v in flat_list:
        if v == delimiter:
            counter += 1
            dd[counter].append(v)
        else:
            dd[counter].append(v)
    return list(dd.values())


sublist_by_delimiter(t, 'x')
[['x', 'a'], ['x'], ['x', 1, 2, 3, 'a', 'a'], ['x', 'e'], ['x']]
```

### Using `dict`

- `3.61 s ± 9.85 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` for the 25M element list

  - with the `defaultdict`: `3.74 s ± 53.7 ms`
- As written, this solution will result in a `KeyError` if the first character is not the delimiter.

```py
def sublist_by_delimiter(flat_list: list, delimiter: str) -> List[list]:
    dd = dict(list)
    counter = 0
    for v in flat_list:
        if v == delimiter:
            counter += 1
            if dd.get(counter) == None:
                dd[counter] =  [v]
        else:
            dd[counter].append(v)
    return list(dd.values())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below function to get desired output.

Try this :

```
def splitList(inputList, delim):
    finalList = []
    chunk = []
    for val in inputList:
        if val == delim:
            finalList.append(chunk)
            chunk = [delim]
        else:
            chunk.append(val)
    finalList.append(chunk)        
    return finalList[1:]


my_input_list = ["x","a","x","x",1,2,3,"a","a","x","e"]
my_output = splitList(my_input_list, "x")    #just call the function with input_list and delimiter to split onto.


print(my_output)

>>> [["x","a"],["x"],["x",1,2,3,"a","a"],["x","e"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

using stack

```
variable = "x" 
input1 = ["x","a","x","x",1,2,3,"a","a","x","e"]

sol = []
tmp = []
for char in input1:
    if char==variable and tmp:
        sol.append(tmp)
        tmp = [char]
    else:
        tmp.append(char)
if tmp:
    sol.append(tmp)
    
print(sol)
```

output

```
 [['x', 'a'], ['x'], ['x', 1, 2, 3, 'a', 'a'], ['x', 'e']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby

variable = "x" 
data = ["x","a","x","x",1,2,3,"a","a","x","e"]
output = []
for k, v in groupby(data, lambda x: x==variable):   #--->[(True, ['x']), (False, ['a']), (True, ['x', 'x']), (False, [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'a']), (True, ['x']), (False, ['e'])]
    v = list(v)
    if k:
        for i in v:
            output.append([i])
    else:
        output[-1].extend(v)
print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
[['x', 'a'], ['x'], ['x', 1, 2, 3, 'a', 'a'], ['x', 'e']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this simple approach with `re`:

```
import re
variable = "x" 
inp = ["x","a","x","x",1,2,3,"a","a","x","e"]
st=''.join(list(map(str,inp)))
regex=f'({variable}[^{variable}]*)'
ls=[[k if not k.isdigit() else int(k) for k in l] for l in re.findall(regex,st)]
print(ls)
```

Output:

```
ls
[['x', 'a'], ['x'], ['x', 1, 2, 3, 'a', 'a'], ['x', 'e']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use double pointers,Try this:

```
var = "x"
l = ["x", "a", "x", "x", 1, 2, 3, "a", "a", "x", "e"]
r = []
left, right = 0, 0
while left < len(l)-1:
    left = right
    if l[left] == var:
        right += 1
        if right < len(l)-1:
            while l[right] != "x":
                right += 1
        else:
            right = len(l)
        r.append(l[left:right])
    left += 1
print(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
indices = [i for i, v in enumerate(input) if v =='x']
res = [input[i:j] for i, j in zip([0]+indices, indices+[None])][1:]
res
```

---

```
[['x', 'a'], ['x'], ['x', 1, 2, 3, 'a', 'a'], ['x', 'e']]
```

Using `itertools's groupby`:

```
class get_indices(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.i = 0

    def __call__(self, value):  # For masking
        self.i += (value == self.value)
        return self.i

res = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(input, key=get_indices('x'))]
res
```

---

```
[['x', 'a'], ['x'], ['x', 1, 2, 3, 'a', 'a'], ['x', 'e']]
```

Answer (score 1):

## This post is a `%%timeit` comparison for solutions available as of this posting

- To everyone that answered, thank you for contributing. There are some great answers. I was working on a similar issue earlier today (2020-07-01), but with a list of lists, where the delimiter would be at index 0 in intermittent lists. I thought it was non-trivial to solve.
- Since there were so many solutions, I thought a comparison would be informative
- The sample data, list `l` has 25_000_000 elements and the first value is `'x'`
- All of the functions in this test correctly return `[['x', 'a'], ['x'], ['x', 1, 2, 3, 'a', 'a'], ['x', 'e'], ['x']]`, for `['x', 'a', 'x', 'x', 1, 2, 3, 'a', 'a', 'x', 'e', 'x']`

### Test Data

```py
import random

random.seed(25)
l = [random.choice(['x', 'a', 'e', 1, 2, 3]) for _ in range(25000000)]
l[0] = 'x'
print(f'Length of list l: {len(l)}')
print(f'First 10 values of list l: {l[:10]}')

Length of list l: 25000000
First 10 values of list l: ['x', 'x', 'a', 'e', 3, 1, 'x', 'e', 'x', 'e']
```

### `%%timeit` tests

```py
%%timeit
pygirl(l)
2.75 s ± 14.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
pygirl2(l)
9 s ± 79.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
trenton(l)
4.78 s ± 36.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
trenton2(l)
3.74 s ± 53.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
trenton3(l)
3.6 s ± 16.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
mrnobody33(l)
9.68 s ± 37.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
rakesh(l)
5.78 s ± 91.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
ansfourtytwo(l)
2.69 s ± 26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
sahasrara62(l)
2.63 s ± 27.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
prashant(l)
2.64 s ± 9.89 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
kevin(l)
# results in
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-270e2f7daf8d> in kevin(test_list)
    101             right += 1
    102             if right < len(test_list)-1:
--> 103                 while test_list[right] != "x":
    104                     right += 1
    105             else:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

### Functions

```py
def pygirl(test_list):
    indices = [i for i, v in enumerate(test_list) if v =='x']
    return [test_list[i:j] for i, j in zip([0]+indices, indices+[None])][1:]


class get_indices(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.i = 0

    def __call__(self, value):  # For masking
        self.i += (value == self.value)
        return self.i
    
    
def pygirl2(test_list):
    return [list(g) for _, g in groupby(test_list, key=get_indices('x'))]


def trenton(test_list):
    result = list()
    chunk = list()
    delimiter = 'x'
    len_test_list = len(test_list)
    for i, v in enumerate(test_list, 1):
        if (v == delimiter) & (i != 1):
            result.append(chunk)
            chunk = [v]
            if i == len_test_list:
                result.append(chunk)
        elif (i == len_test_list):
            chunk.append(v)
            result.append(chunk)
        else:
            chunk.append(v)       
    return result


def trenton2(test_list):
    dd = defaultdict(list)  # defaultdict
    delim = 'x'
    counter = 0
    for v in test_list:
        if v == delim:
            counter += 1
            dd[counter].append(v)
        else:
            dd[counter].append(v)
    return list(dd.values())


def trenton3(test_list):
    dd = dict()  # regular dict
    delim = 'x'
    counter = 0
    for v in test_list:
        if v == delim:
            counter += 1
            if dd.get(counter) == None:
                dd[counter] = [v]
        else:
            dd[counter].append(v)
        
    return list(dd.values())


def mrnobody33(test_list):
    variable = "x" 
    st=''.join(list(map(str,test_list)))
    regex=f'({variable}[^{variable}]*)'
    return [[k if not k.isdigit() else int(k) for k in v] for v in re.findall(regex,st)]


def rakesh(test_list):
    variable = "x" 
    output = []
    for k, v in groupby(test_list, lambda x: x==variable):
        v = list(v)
        if k:
            for i in v:
                output.append([i])
        else:
            output[-1].extend(v)
    return output


def ansfourtytwo(test_list):
    variable = 'x'
    idx = [ix for ix, val in enumerate(test_list) if val==variable]
    return [test_list[i:j] for i,j in zip(idx, idx[1:]+[len(test_list)])]


def sahasrara62(test_list):
    variable = "x" 
    sol = []
    tmp = []
    for char in test_list:
        if char==variable and tmp:
            sol.append(tmp)
            tmp = [char]
        else:
            tmp.append(char)
    if tmp:
        sol.append(tmp)
    return sol


def prashant(test_list):
    delim = 'x'
    finalList = []
    chunk = []
    for val in test_list:
        if val == delim:
            finalList.append(chunk)
            chunk = [delim]
        else:
            chunk.append(val)
    finalList.append(chunk)        
    return finalList[1:]


def kevin(test_list):
    var = "x"
    r = []
    left, right = 0, 0
    while left < len(test_list)-1:
        left = right
        if test_list[left] == var:
            right += 1
            if right < len(test_list)-1:
                while test_list[right] != "x":
                    right += 1
            else:
                right = len(test_list)
            r.append(test_list[left:right])
        left += 1
    return r
```