# Split list of integers based on specific value

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I split a list of integers based on specific value? See following example for instance:

```
inp = [1, 3, 4, 5, -999, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5, -999, 85, 82, 84]

outs = magic_function(inp)

>> [[1,3,4,5], [0,0,1,3,5], [85,82,84]] # expected output is like this
```

The output will be a list of list which splited based on -999. So far I handle it with for-loop or convert it to string and then use `str.split('-999')` but I would like to know is there any elegant (more efficient) way to do this?

Comment: In the above link, [this particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15358422/2296458) has a one-line solution to do just this

Answer (score 1):

this would work:

```
from itertools import groupby

inp = [1, 3, 4, 5, -999, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5, -999, 85, 82, 84]

sep = -999
ret = [list(items) for key, items in groupby(inp, lambda x: x == sep) if not key]

print(ret)  # [[1, 3, 4, 5], [0, 0, 1, 3, 5], [85, 82, 84]]
```

where i use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to split the list.