# Python split string with some items of the string in order

Tags: python

Surpose the string:

```
'abcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcde'
```

split by :

```
'cdebbe'
```

output:

```
'ab c d e a b cdea b cd e abcdeabcde'
```

This means  split string

```
'abcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcde'
```

by indexes

```
[2,3,4,6,10,14]
```

How to do this by Python? This question is similar to [Split a list into parts based on a set of indexes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198512/split-a-list-into-parts-based-on-a-set-of-indexes-in-python)
If follow the answers the out put is :

```
['ab', 'c', 'd', 'ea', 'bcde', 'abcd', 'eabcdeabcdeabcde']
```

isnt the expected output.

Comment: The logic of the output is quite unclear

Comment: Your string doesn't contain any "cdebbe".

Comment: Split first by 'c' then by 'd' ...

Comment: Split by c: `['ab', string]`, split by d: `['abc', string]`

Comment: use list() method

Comment: @Itay I improved the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quite matches your expected output, but I don't know what's the logic when `'cdebbe'` reaches the end.

```
s = 'abcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcde'
split = 'cdebbe'

result = []
for c in split:
    left, center, s = s.partition(c)
    if left:
        result.append(left)
    result.append(center)

print(' '.join(result)) # ab c d e a b cdea b cd e
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks, the end doesnt matter.

Answer (score 2):

```
'abcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcde'.split('cdebbe')
```

But your string does not contain 'cdebbe' substring, so result is a list with one string:

```
['abcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcde']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'abcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcde'
new = []

for i,char in enumerate('cdebbe'):
    new.append(s.split(char)[:i+1])

print new
>>[['ab'], ['abc', 'eabc'], ['abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd'], ['a', 'cdea', 'cdea', 'cdea'], ['a', 'cdea', 'cdea', 'cdea', 'cdea'], ['abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd']]
```

This will split your string by all letters in 'cdebbe' independently.

doing a bit of manipulation to this we can get the response you require. But it's not exactly what you expected.

```
new2 = []
for i, x in enumerate(new):
    new2.append(new[i][-1])

print new2 
>>['ab', 'eabc', 'abcd', 'cdea', 'cdea', 'abcd']
```

Quick explanation: 'ab' is the first part of the string split at 'c', 'eabc' is the second part of the string when split on 'd' etc etc