# Python find indices in an array based on conditions

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, append

I have a list/**array(can make them arrays, doesn't matter)**:

```
array = [1,2,1,1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5]
```

I would like to create a `new_array` FROM `array` which looks like this:

```
new_array = [[1,2],[1],[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

The logic I came up with was to start with `a=0,b=1` and loop through `array`, when the value of `array[a] < array[b]`, then `a+=1`,`b+=1`, but if the value of `array[a]>=array[b]`, then append the value of `b`:
Here is what I tried:

```
index_1 = [] # This will be the list which will have the FIRST index 
index_2 = [] # This will be the list which will have the SECOND index
a = 0
b = 1
for i in array:
    if i[a] < i[b]:
        a = a+1
        b = b+1
    elif i[a] >= i[b]:
        index_2.append(b)
        index_1.append(a)
```

So `index_1` will have the first index and `index_2` will have the second index and then, we can create the `new_array` by:

```
new_array = [(array[start:end]) for start,end in zip(index_1,index_2)]
```

Unfortunately, even though my idea is correct, the loop stops in `if i[a]<i[b]` because of `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.`.

Comment: Those are not arrays.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: doesn't matter, I can make them `numpy arrays` or let them be `lists`.

Comment: You can just try to `print(i)`, what do you get? So actually, what you need is `for _ in range(len(array))`, `array[a]` and `array[b]`. `i` is already an item inside `array`.

Comment: Of course it matters. Not only are the performance characterstics different, you can't really have staggered arrays in `numpy`, as your `new_array` implies

Comment: @Sraw: so you mean I have to modify my `for` loop ? If so how ? Is everything else correct ?

Comment: I think you can simply have a loop that starts over when a 1 is approached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can go through the array directly by the elements (more precisely by a pair of neighboring elements) simultaneously forming the result.

We initialize our result with a sublist of the 1st element of the array and then:

if the next element is greater than the previous one, we add it to the last sublist

otherwise -  we add a new sublist with this element to the result.

```
array = [1,2,1,1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5]

new_array = [[array[0]]] # assume the array is not empty
for a,b in zip(array, array[1:]):
    if a<b:
        new_array[-1].append(b)
    else:
        new_array.append([b])

print(new_array)
# [[1, 2], [1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

---

#### UPD.

Alternatively, we can implement it with indices.
(based on [this answer by @fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1198876/8786820))

First, prepare indices to split the array:

```
idxs_to_split = [idx for idx in range(1, len(array)) if not array[idx-1] < array[idx]]
pairs = zip([0] + idxs_to_split, idxs_to_split + [None])
```

Second, implement the splitting itself:

```
new_array = [array[i:j] for i,j in pairs]

print(new_array)
# [[1, 2], [1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Can you explain ?

Comment: What does `new_array[-1].append(b)` do? I can understand `new_array.append([b])`

Comment: `list[-1]` refers to the last element in a list, in this case it is another list, to which we append

Comment: @ThePredator, `new_array[-1]` is the current last sub-list of the result.
In the above expression, we append `b` to it

Comment: When we are zipping, where are we using `a` ? I only see that we append `b`.

Comment: @ThePredator, `a` is needed for the comparison, which determines how exactly we will add `b` to the result

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple approach, just keep track of the previous, and check if it is smaller. If it is, append to sub. If it isnt, append sub to the new list, then create a new sub. Always append sub at the end.

```
>>> new_array = []
>>> array = [1,2,1,1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5]
>>> sub = []
>>> prev = float('-inf')
>>> for x in array:
...     if prev < x:
...         sub.append(x)
...     else:
...         new_array.append(sub)
...         sub = [x]
...     prev = x
...
>>> new_array.append(sub)
>>> new_array
[[1, 2], [1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def g(l):
    acc = []
    for i in l:
        if not acc:
            acc.append(i)
        else:
            if acc[-1] < i:
                acc.append(i)
            else:
                yield acc
                acc = [i]
    yield acc
```

Here's a generator version that should work for all iterables. Usage would be something like

```
list(g(array))
```

And gives the desired

```
[[1, 2], [1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply checked for two conditions, 1. If next element == 1  and 2. If j is at last element of the list.

```
array = [1,2,1,1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5]
newList = []

j = 0
k = 0
while j < len(array)-1:
    if array[j+1] ==1:
        newList.append(array[k:j+1])
        k = j+1
    if  j+2==len(array):
        newList.append(array[k:j+2])
        k = j + 1
   j +=1
print newList
```

Comment: The above was just a minimal example. I have different floating values in my original list. So I cannot use the condition of `==1`. Thanks for your effort anyway.

Comment: Okay. I hope you get the answer. Happy solving :)