# Split a list into sublists based on a set of indexes in Python

Tags: python

I have a list similar to below

```
['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
```

and I would like to separate by a list of index

```
[1,4]
```

In this case, it will be

```
[['a'],['b','c'],['d','e','f','g','h','i','j']]
```

As

```
[:1] =['a']

[1:4] = ['b','c']

[4:] = ['d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
```

Case 2: if the list of index is

```
[0,6]
```

It will be

```
[[],['a','b','c','d','e'],['f','g','h','i','j']]
```

As

```
[:0] = []

[0:6] = ['a','b','c','d','e']

[6:] = ['f','g','h','i','j']
```

Case 3 if the index is

```
[2,5,7]
```

it will be
    [['a','b'],['c','d','e'],['h','i','j']]
As

```
[:2] =['a','b']
[2:5] = ['c','d','e']
[5:7] = ['f','g']
[7:] = ['h','i','j']
```

Comment: If your question is how to obtain these sublists: why not use a simple loop?

Comment: This sounds only 99% like a homework. What do you want to achieve with this? Or in other words, what does the homework want you to do? You allready split lists based on a set of indexes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a list into parts based on a set of indexes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198512/split-a-list-into-parts-based-on-a-set-of-indexes-in-python)

Comment: The slices that you are showing aren't consistent. `[0:6] = ['a','b','c','d','e']` should be `['a','b','c','d','e','f']` and `[1:4] = ['b','c']` should be `['b','c','d']`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
mylist = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
myindex = [1,4]

[mylist[s:e] for s, e in zip([0]+myindex, myindex+[None])]
```

**Output**

```
[['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']]
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution is using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

def do_split(lst, slices):
    return [sl.tolist()for sl in np.split(lst, slices)]

splits = do_split(a, [2,5,7])

Out[49]:
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g'], ['h', 'i', 'j']]
```

Comment: This will be faster than my approach by avoiding copies, +1!

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

newlist = []

divide = [2,5,7]
divide = [0]+divide+[len(a)]
for i in range(1,len(divide)):
  newlist.append(a[divide[i-1]:divide[i]])

print(newlist)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7], [8,9,10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function to do what you're asking

```
def splitter(_list, *args):
    args_list = [0]
    args_list += args
    args_list.append(len(_list))
    new_list = []
    for i, arg in enumerate(args_list):
        try:
            new_list.append(_list[arg:args_list[i+1]])

        except IndexError:
            continue
    return new_list
```

The function can be used like this:

```
mylist = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
splitter(mylist, 2, 4)
```

Which returns:

```
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]
```