# What is a pythonic way to create slices based on excluded indices?

Tags: python, slice, intervals

I have a list of indices to exclude:

```
idx = [1, 3, 6]
```

and I want to automatically get 4 intervals/slices based on these indices, thanks to this post [Split a list into parts based on a set of indexes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198512/split-a-list-into-parts-based-on-a-set-of-indexes-in-python):

```
slices = [list[:1], list[2:3], list[4:6], list[7:]]
```

What is a pythonic way to do that?

** **EDIT**
I solved it using a list comprehension and zip function:

```
'[list[i + 1: j] for i, j in zip([-1, *idx], [*idx, None])]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your attempt to do it.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi: The link question is not a duplicate (it doesn't create slices).

Comment: Filip, since you have solved it, you should post your solution as an answer.

Comment: That solution might yield an empty list if 0 is to be excluded (`list[0:0] -> []`) , and an IndexOutOfRangeException if `len(list)-1` is to be excluded (`list[len(list):] -> IndexOutOfRangeException`). So I would not consider it a solution yet