# How to partition list so that there are no partitions with same characters

Tags: python, list

So first  I want to partition list to every possible partition, without changing the order of list.
Like this:

```
[['a', 'b', 'a']]
[['a'], ['b', 'a']]
[['a', 'b'], ['a']]
[['a'], ['b'], ['a']]
```

Count of ways to do this is 4. I want to remove all possible partitions that have same characters in the part.
For same input than last time:

```
[['a'], ['b', 'a']]
[['a', 'b'], ['a']]
[['a'], ['b'], ['a']]
```

Removed     [['a', 'b', 'a']]    , because it has 2 a's in same part.
How to do it in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) on [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) to create all the different ways to partition the list. Once the list is partitioned filter out if any of the parts contains duplicated elements.

```
from itertools import combinations, chain


def partition(alist, indices):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/1198876/4001592
    pairs = zip(chain([0], indices), chain(indices, [None]))
    return (alist[i:j] for i, j in pairs)


lst = ["a", "b", "a"]

result = []
split_count = len(lst)
for i in range(split_count):
    for combination in combinations(range(1, split_count), i):
        parts = [part for part in partition(lst, combination)]
        if all(len(part) == len(set(part)) for part in parts):
            result.append(parts)

for parts in result:
    print(parts)
```

**Output**

```
[['a'], ['b', 'a']]
[['a', 'b'], ['a']]
[['a'], ['b'], ['a']]
```